# How do you produce a random 0 or 1 with random.rand

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to produce a 0 or 1 with numpy's random.rand.

`np.random.rand()` produces a random float between 0 and 1 but not just a 0 or a 1.

Thank you.

Comment: You can `round` it.

Comment: you can also avoid numpy altogether if you just need to generate 1 random output. there is the random module for that with [randint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [np.random.choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) with a list of `[0,1]`, or use [np.random.radint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) with a range of `0,2`

```
In [1]: import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                                                 

In [2]: np.random.choice([0,1])                                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[2]: 0

In [5]: np.random.choice([0,1])                                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[5]: 1

In [8]: np.random.randint(2)                                                                                                                                                                                             
Out[8]: 0

In [9]: np.random.randint(2)                                                                                                                                                                                             
Out[9]: 1
```

You can also use the [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#) module for the equivalent of these functions

Answer (score 3):

You can use `np.random.randint(low, high=None, size=None)`.

```
>>> np.random.randint(0,2,10)
array([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])
>>> np.random.randint(2)
0
>>> np.random.randint(2)
1
```

Fore more details, you can refer to https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.random.random_integers`

```
random_int= np.random.random_integers(0,1)
print (random_int)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using `np.random.randint()` This function takes a range as an input. 
For example,

```
>>> np.random.randint(2)
```

This will give you an output of either `0` or `1`

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers, it is possible to simply do

```
p_True = 0.5 # 50% probability that you get 1
your_bool = p_True >= np.random.rand() # >= because rand returns a float between 0 and 1, excluding 1.
```

You can have a biased sample by changing `p_true`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use np.random.choice with a list of [0,1] and a size to get a random choice matrix like this:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.random.choice([0,1], size=(3,4))
Out[2]: array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
               [0, 1, 1, 0],
               [1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason to specifically use `np.random.rand`? This function outputs a float as noted in the question and previous answers, and you would need thresholding to obtain an int.

`scipy.stats.bernoulli(p)` directly outputs a 1 with probability `p` and 0 with probability `1-p`.